# How to reduce the number of errors to zero in the HPLIP's hp-check output for debugging purposes?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, hp, hplip

I have installed HPLIP from deb-package with simple `sudo apt-get install hplip` and installed driver/plugin with `hp-plugin`.

But the output of `hp-check` contains errors.
It is known that output of this command is often used for debugging purposes.

The number of errors on clean systems:

```
| Ubuntu version | Errors |
|----------------|--------|
|    16.04 LTS   |   13   |
|    18.04 LTS   |   14   |
|    20.04 LTS   |   22   |
```

(number of errors may vary for different flavors)

Is it possible to reduce them to zero?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the number of errors to zero we need:

1. Enable *Source Code* repositories in *Software & Updates* (`software-properties-gtk`)
2. Install build-dependencies and packages:

   ```
   sudo apt-get build-dep hplip
   sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool libtool-bin libcups2-dev cups-bsd cups-client avahi-utils gtk2-engines-pixbuf xsane
   ```

   Some additional packages are also required:

   - For Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 19.10 -

     ```
     sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4 python3-dbus.mainloop.qt python3-notify2
     ```
   - For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS -

     ```
     sudo apt-get install libcups2 python3-pyqt5 gtk2-engines-pixbuf python3-notify2 python3-dbus.mainloop.pyqt5
     ```

     (but really this is not enough, so I have reported [bug 1881401](https://pad.lv/1881401))
3. Run `hp-check` again and see

   > ```
   > No errors or warnings.
   > ```

   message.

And then we can check other possible problems of HPLIP for example with `hp-doctor` (it contains output of `hp-check` and other tests).